# class, ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

При выполнении кода

```
import requests
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui,QtCore
from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
import json

r = requests.get('https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/TQBR/securities.json?iss.meta=off&iss.only=securities&securities.columns=SECNAME,SECID')
pricesale = (r.json()['securities']['data']

class mywindow(mydesign.QtWidgets):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.comboBox()
    
    def comboBox(self):
        for i in pricesale:
            self.ui.comboBox.addItem(','.join(i))
        self.ui.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
     
    def onActivated(self,text):
        self.ui.label.setText(text)
        self.ui.label.adjustSize()     
  
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
 
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

появляется ошибка

```
class mywindow(mydesign.QtWidgets):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

помогите разобраться как пофиксить

Comment: Скобку не закрыли в предыдущей строке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скобку не закрыли в строке:

```
pricesale = (r.json()['securities']['data']
```